# Foreign key in different database connection

Tags: mysql, database, docker

While building my app, I came across a problem. I have some database tables with information, I want to reuse for different applications. Mainly for authentication and user privileges.

That is why i decided to split my database into two, one for user data (data I will need for other applications) and another for application related data (data I will need only for this).

In some cases, I need to reference a foreign key from one database on another database. I had no problem doing so while databases are in the same connection. I did it like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `database1`.`table1` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foreign_key` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `table1_foreign_key_foreign` (`foreign_key`),
  CONSTRAINT `table1_foreign_key_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`foreign_key`) REFERENCES `database2`.`table2` (`id`)
);
```

Now here is my problem. I am getting to know `Docker` and I would like to create a container for each database. If my understanding is correct, each container acts as a different connection.

Is it even possible to reference a foreign key on different database connection?

Is there another way of referencing a foreign key from one `Docker` container on another?

Any suggestions or comments would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Having a foreign key cross database boundaries is a bad idea for multiple reasons.

1. Scaling out: You are tying the databases to the same instance. Moving a database to a new instance becomes much more complicated, and you definitely do not want to end up with a FK constraint running over a linked server.  Please, no.  Don't.
2. Disaster Recovery: Your DR process has a significant risk.  Are your backups capturing the data at the exact same point in time?  If not, there is the risk that the related data will not match after a restore.  Even a difference of a few seconds can invalidate the integrity of the relationship.
3. Different subsystems:  Each database requires resources.  Some are explicit, others are shared, but there is overhead for each database running in your instance.
4. Security: Each database has its own security implementation.  Different logins and access permissions.  If a user in your DATA database needs to lookup a value against the USER database, you'll need to manage permissions in both.  Segregating the data by database doesn't solve or enhance your security, it just makes it more complicated.  The overhead to manage the security for the sensitive data doesn't change, you'll still need to review and manage users and permissions based on the data (not the location of the data).  You should be able to implement exactly the same security controls within the single database.

Comment: Thank you for your argumented answer. I came to realisation, that my app architecture needs to be improven. I will probably make authorization and user privilege check via API and security tokens. That way I will also be able to login to all my apps by single login page. Thanks again for sharing your view and helping me see outside of my bubble.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. You can not create FK to different instance of DB (or other Docker container in your case).
You may try to make this check on application level.